# Trouble changing React class into a function

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I heard that classes are hardly used in React anymore, since functions work so well. So, I got `react-datepicker` class copied elsewhere and I'm now trying to change it into a function.

It doesn't quite work correctly, it gives me today's date no matter what I choose. Calendar chooses the day I want, but it passes today's date on.

Class:

```
class CalendarClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date()
    };
  }

  handleChange = date => {
    this.setState({
      date: date
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <DatePicker
          selected={this.state.date}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          minDate={new Date()}
          dropdownMode="select"
        />
        <AddMassageDate date={this.state.date} dateData={this.props.dateData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Function:

```
function CalendarClass ({ date, dateData }) {

  let [day, setDay] = useState(new Date());

  let handleChange = day => {
    setDay(day);
    date = day;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <DatePicker
        selected={day}
        onChange={handleChange}
        minDate={new Date()}
        dropdownMode="select"
      />
      <AddMassageDate date={date} dateData={dateData} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Classes are not being removed from react and are still very viable. reworking an entire application is probably not something you want to do. Just a side note

Comment: Note: I changed `date` to `day` into the function, as `date` was already defined. I wonder, if that causes the fails somehow?

Comment: your function expects a date from props, do you send it?

Comment: @MohammedShammout Yeah, it works with the class. Nothing outside of the class/function is changed. Good point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `date` prop is change, but this change is not persisted between renders of the component. I would suggest removing the `date` prop and only use the `day` state hook.

```js
function CalendarClass ({ dateData }) {

  let [day, setDay] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div>
      <DatePicker
        selected={day}
        onChange={d => setDay(d)}
        minDate={new Date()}
        dropdownMode="select"
      />
      <AddMassageDate date={day} dateData={dateData} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let's refactor your component like this

```
const CalendarClass = props => {
const [day, setDay] = useState(new Date());
const { date, dateData } = props;

  const handleChange = day => {
    setDay(day);
    date = day;
  };


    return (
       <>
      <DatePicker
        selected={day}
        onChange={handleChange}
        minDate={new Date()}
        dropdownMode="select"
      />
      <AddMassageDate date={date} dateData={dateData} />
    </>
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, probably because `day` should be called `date` here too, as explained in the other answer. Is there a reason you changed `let` to `const`? Is there difference between the two?

Comment: `const` is constant and if you don't want to change it in your code is better to use `const` instead of `let`.`let` is changeble.i just refactored your class component to Function component.i don't know anything about the props.it's on you.